# Failing to compare array of two objects in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can someone please please have a look at below code and help me debug whats going wrong, the code is expected to return

```
1
1
```

but it is giving

```
1
0
```

Code

```
inputs  = [{'segment_id': 826502001, 'version': 'v2'},{'segment_id': 827768001, 'version': 'v1'}]

def ch():
    
    def function(segment_id,version):
        for item in inputs:
            if item['segment_id'] == segment_id and item['version'] == version:
                return 0
            else:
                return 1
    return function

def main():

    check = ch()
    print(check(827768001 , 'v1') ) 
    print(check(826502001,  'v2'))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

Comment: `return` stop your loop on first iteration anyway

Answer (score 3):

You want:

```
        for item in inputs:
            if item['segment_id'] == segment_id and item['version'] == version:
                return 1
        else:
            return 0
```

Or simply:

```
        for item in inputs:
            if item['segment_id'] == segment_id and item['version'] == version:
                return 1
        return 0
```

In other words, return 1 if any match, but if none match then return 0.

---

Addendum: it could also be done as a one-liner if you wanted:

```
return int(any(item['segment_id'] == segment_id and item['version'] == version for item in inputs))
```

Comment: @OlvinRoght I wanted something tolerably close to the original code but I'll add it as an alternative.

Comment: I've added something using `any` just as an addendum - not sure if that is the sort of thing you had in mind?

Answer (score 1):

This is because a function can only return one item, but you are trying to loop over 2 values and return 2 values in `function()`.

You could append the values you want to return into a list, and then return the list instead.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the [in membership operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations) to test if a dict is contained in the list.

Internally this will be resolved as an `any` check of the list members - see details in the link above.

```
inputs  = [{'segment_id': 826502001, 'version': 'v2'},{'segment_id': 827768001, 'version': 'v1'}]

def check(segment_id,version):
    return int({'segment_id': segment_id, 'version': version} in inputs)

print(check(827768001 , 'v1')) 
print(check(826502001,  'v2'))
print(check(827768001 , 'v3'))
```

returns as expected

```
1
1
0
```

Comment: Awesome !! didnt know something like this exists. Thanks